# How to denote a 64-bit numeral in C#?

Tags: c#

In C++ if I wanted to denote a 64-bit numeral I'd add `LL` at the end as such:

```
__int64 n = 1000000LL * 10000LL;
```

Is there a way to do the same in C#?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar

```
Int64 n = 1000000L * 10000L;
```

Which is really a long

```
long n = 1000000L * 10000L;


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Int64 num = 1000000L * 10000L;
        long n = 1000000L * 10000L;

        Console.WriteLine(num*n);
    }
```

Will print 7766279631452241920